# How do I remove base64 strings from an arbitrary string?

Tags: python, regex, replace, base64, data-cleaning

I have a string in Python. I want to remove base64 strings from it. I read about [the base64 spec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Decoding_Base64_with_padding) and [looked around SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how%20to%20remove%20base64%20strings%20python%3F) but it doesn't look like I was able to find a clean way to remove them.

I tried a couple of hacky regexes but it makes my string worse; e.g., it changes the word `problem` to `lem`:

```py
def remove_base64_strings(text: str) -> str:
    """
    Remove base64 encoded strings from a string.
    """
    # Regular expression for matching potential base64 strings
    base64_pattern = r"(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)?"
    # Replace found base64 strings with an empty string
    return re.sub(base64_pattern, "", text)
```

or

```py
import re

base64_regex = r'^([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==)$'

base64_strings = re.findall(base64_regex, text)
```

Is there a robust way to remove base64 strings otherwise?

I was thinking of splitting the words by spaces. Then finding a string that matched the above pattern and was at least 12 characters, since base64 strings look like random long strings and I want to remove them for sure.

---

I tried this:

```py
def remove_base64_words(text: str, threshold_length: int = 24) -> str:
    """
    Remove words that are suspected to be Base64 encoded strings from a sentence.

    Args:
    sentence (str): The sentence from which to remove Base64 encoded words.
    threshold_length (int): The minimum length of a word to be considered a Base64 encoded string.

    Returns:
    str: The sentence with suspected Base64 encoded words removed.
    """
    # # Regex pattern for Base64 encoded strings
    # base64_pattern = r"\b(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)?\b"
    # base64_pattern = r"^([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}){5,}([A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)?$"
    # base64_pattern = r"\b(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)?\b"

    # # Function to replace suspected Base64 encoded words
    # def replace_base64_word(matchobj):
    #     word = matchobj.group(0)
    #     if len(word) >= threshold_length:
    #         return ""
    #     else:
    #         return word

    # # Replace words in the sentence that match the pattern and are above the threshold length
    # return re.sub(base64_pattern, replace_base64_word, sentence)
    """
    Remove words from the text that are of length 28 or more, 
    are multiples of 4, and not found in the English dictionary.

    Args:
    text (str): The input text.

    Returns:
    str: The text with suspected Base64-like non-dictionary words removed.
    """
    import nltk
    nltk.download('words')
    from nltk.corpus import words

    # Set of English words
    english_words = set(words.words())

    # Split the text into words
    words_in_text = text.split()

    # Filter out words of specific length properties that are not in the English dictionary
    filtered_words = [word for word in words_in_text if not (len(word) >= threshold_length and len(word) % 4 == 0 and word.lower() not in english_words)]

    # Reassemble the text
    return ' '.join(filtered_words)
```

Unit tests:

```
    # base64
    # Unit tests
    test_sentences = [
        ("This is a test with no base64", "This is a test with no base64"),
        ("Base64 example: TWFuIGlzIGRpc3Rpbmd1aXNoZWQ=", "Base64 example: "),
        ("Short== but not base64", "Short== but not base64"),
        ("ValidBase64== but too short", "ValidBase64== but too short"),
        ("Mixed example with TWFuIGlzIGRpc3Rpbmd1aXNoZWQ= base64", "Mixed example with  base64"),
    ]
    for input_sentence, expected_output in test_sentences:
        our_output: str = remove_base64_words(input_sentence)
        print(f'Trying to remove Base64: {input_sentence=} --> {our_output=} {expected_output=}')
        # print(f'Trying to remove Base64: {input_sentence=} {expected_output=}')
```

Comment: Can you add some sample input and expected output to your question?

Comment: @Nick I just did

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/690180/remove-all-base64-blocks-from-a-file

Comment: Do you know anything about the data encoded as base64? That would massively increase your ability to filter them out without hurting anything else.

Comment: How does the input text end up with base64-encoded strings mixed with regular words in the first place? In all real-world scenarios I can think of base64-encoded strings are always unambiguously stored in a structured format. I can't imagine any actual usage of base64 where a base64-encoded string would be simply inserted into a regular sentence without any clear markings. Please provide some background information for your use case for this question to be answerable.

Comment: The code at the end of the question looks reasonable, but is apparently unrelated to your attempt. Can you please [edit] to clarify their relationship, and add actual test cases for the function which is apparently your own, including examples of text that it is being invoked on?

Comment: Please clarify what you actually consider base64. Your question is showing at least three different definitions: anything matching base64, long sequences matching base64 and anything that is not an English word. All of these have different false positives and negatives *and it is not clear from the question which of these are acceptable*. Note that the task is inherently ambiguous, so the "true" solution is to fix whatever is providing this broken data in the first place.

Comment: You could try to [decode the extracted Base64 strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html?highlight=base64#base64.b64decode) as an extra guard against false matches.

Comment: @blhsing that is what I was thinking too tbh.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it obvious? Your regex does not implement the "at least 12 characters" requirement and will replace any string, regardless of length, which matches the general pattern.

A very small tweak to the pattern to require at least 12 characters is to change the first `*` to `{3,}`, i.e. require at least three repetitions of the groups of four characters at the beginning.

```
    base64_pattern = r"(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}){3,}(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)?"
```

Your pattern has another flaw in that it misses any base64 strings with three padding characters at the end. The fix for that should be similarly obvious:

```
    base64_pattern = r"(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}){3,}(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]={3}|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)?"
```

However, this is probably still too greedy. You are not showing how you are calling your function, but the expression should probably have token boundaries around it if you are attempting to run it on stretches of arbitrary text. Because some base64 characters are not "word characters" the simple `\b` won't work here, so I have implemented this using a negative lookbehind at the beginning and a negative lookahead at the end to ensure that you don't have matches which start or end in the middle of a longer token.

```
    base64_pattern = r"(?<![A-Za-z0-9+/=])(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}){3,}(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]={3}|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)?(?![A-Za-z0-9+/=])"
```

This is still inherently imprecise because there are many English (or otherwise) words which are 12 characters long and a multiple of four characters but not base64; `grep -Ecx '([A-Za-z]{4}){3,}' /usr/share/dict/words`   returns
24048 matches on my system.

Comment: This will still incorrectly match many regular words whose lengths are multiples of 4 and are at least 12. The question as it is cannot be answered without the OP providing more context.

Comment: @blhsing Thanks, I updated with a comment about the lack of clarity and another guard to implement (something like) token boundaries.